# UNCSS command line under Windows for Sites with Authentication

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, uncss

I have a multipage web application written using AngularJs, Bootstrap 3 and HTML5. I was planning to use UNCSS to optimise my CSS. I do not use grut or such workflow/build mechanism. But have node.js installed in my machine.

1. Can I run UNCSS at the command line of a windows PC?
2. If so how should I run it? There is no executable program
3. How will it go pass the Authentication page comes as the fist page of the app?

regards,
Ish